# Does anyone know where to find free database design templates?

Tags: database, templates

I'm obviously not talking about a full solution, but just a good starting point for common applications for software architects. It could be for a CMS, e-commerce storefront, address book, etc. A UML diagram is not essential, but a table schema with data types in the least. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the [Library of Free Data Models](http://databaseanswers.org/data_models/) from DatabaseAnswers.org -- might be a good starting point.  I can't vouch for the quality, but there is a lot here...

Comment: The link is unavailable now. Here I found the archive version: https://web.archive.org/web/20210508051645/http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index_all_models.htm

Answer (score 0):

Open source?

[DB-UML might work for you](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dbuml#item3rd-1).

EDIT:

Oh!  The [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/) is good.

Answer (score 0):

[The mondial database.](http://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/)  Is used for learning about DBMSs.  If you need something quick and dirty to bang around.

Answer (score 0):

try this one... [database design document template](http://www.klariti.com/software-development-lifecycle-templates/database-design-document-template.shtml).
very good and usefull template.
but it isnt free.. you have to buy it.. :(